# os.rename() not working in my python script

Tags: python, operating-system, rename, windowserror

I'm writing a script to change all of the .mp3, .m4a and .m4p files in the directory './itunes and music/F14/' to another title. I'm able to get the filenames, and using hsaudiotag I can get the title tag. However, when I try to rename the file to the title tag it give me the error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Here's my code:

```
from hsaudiotag import auto
import os

def main():
    for filename in os.listdir('./itunes and music/F14/'):
        print(filename)
        os.rename(filename, filename[2:])
        myfile = auto.File('./itunes and music/F14/'+filename)
        print(myfile.title)
        if filename.endswith(".mp3"):
            print('3')
            os.rename(filename, myfile.title+".mp3")
        elif filename.endswith(".m4a"):
            print('4a')
            os.rename(filename, myfile.title+".m4a")
        elif filename.endswith(".m4p"):
            print('4p')
            os.rename(filename, myfile.title+".m4p")

main()
```

All of the print statements are just to debug, and they all are working properly. It's just the os.rename() function that isn't.

Comment: Is the file name being printed properly?

Comment: Yeah, all of the filenames are being printed OK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specify file path, not just filename.

```
from hsaudiotag import auto
import os

def main():
    d = './itunes and music/F14/'
    for filename in os.listdir(d):
        print(filename)
        filepath = os.path.join(d, filename)
        os.rename(filepath, filepath[2:])
        myfile = auto.File(filepath)
        print(myfile.title)
        if filename.endswith(".mp3"):
            print('3')
            os.rename(filepath, os.path.join(d, myfile.title+".mp3"))
        elif filename.endswith(".m4a"):
            print('4a')
            os.rename(filepath, os.path.join(d, myfile.title+".m4a"))
        elif filename.endswith(".m4p"):
            print('4p')
            os.rename(filepath, os.path.join(d, myfile.title+".m4p"))

main()
```

Comment: This works for all the .mp3 files, on the .m4a and .m4p files I'm still getting:

WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Comment: @user2528556, Check if title does contain invalid character for file name. `\ / : * ? < > |`. Replace such characters.